# Alpha blending on the edges of an UIImage

Tags: iphone, uiimage, transparency, alpha, blending

I have two rectangular images: one is foreground, the other one is background. I am trying to blend the edges of the foreground image so that the foreground image looks like it is "part" of the background image. In other words, I am trying to apply a transparency effect, with the opacity of the foreground image decreasing from 100% at the center of the image down to 0% at the edges. I have found that this operation is sometimes referred by different names, such as: alpha compositing, alpha blending, edge feathering or edge transparency. Here is a more detailed description of the effect I am trying to obtain: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing

I have looked at the CGContext documentation, but I haven't found any function that would do that out of the box.

Is there any way to do that using CGContext or even OpenGL? Would there be a way to do it on a non-rectangular image? I know, all images are rectangular, but I mean an image with let's say, a circle in it, and a transparent area all around.

Comment: If you are at liberty to change the image itself, go for that way. Using CGContext is possible but harder than simply flipping a switch. A general approach would be to create a bitmap context, render your image onto it (with any transform that applies), and then change the alpha values in that bitmap context, and then turn the bitmap context into a displayable image again. Not pretty.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609132/iphone-replacing-a-block-of-pixels-in-an-image-with-another-block-of-pixls/4609333#4609333, and use `view.renderInContext:` to apply custom pixel level editing to any view.

Comment: @mvds: thanks for your help, I found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CGImageCreateWithMask()` function in the iOS library can do alpha blending with decreasing opacity on the edges. It's possible to get something to work by combining the code in these two links:

http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html

[Creating mask with CGImageMaskCreate is all black (iphone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633051/creating-mask-with-cgimagemaskcreate-is-all-black-iphone)

The level of gray (from black to white) of each pixel in the mask will define the level of opacity during blending.